# How do I override Angular $resource save?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have created a service like so:

```
fbApp.factory('Post', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('posts/:postId', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {postId: 'index'}, isArray: true}
    });
}]);
```

In my controller I am saving new posts like so:

```
var postData = angular.copy($scope.formData);
postData.published = $filter('date')($scope.formData.published, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'UTC');
var post = new Post({Post:postData});
post.$save();
```

I want to change the service's save method so that instead of `new Post({Post:postData}).$save()` I can simply do `new Post(postData).$save()`.
I took a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource and I believe the key is to override the `$resource.$save()` method or use `transformRequest`. Documentation on either is lacking.

Comment: can pass the data as argument of `save()`

Comment: @downvoter please state the reason for the downvote so that others can benefit

Comment: sure, but that does not answer the question of how can the method be overridden.

Comment: not really clear what you mean by over ride or why your situation differs from normal $resource usage. Personally I typically pass my data to `save()` instead of `$save()` to create new record

Comment: I want to transform my data prior to sending it to the back-end service. my service expects my data in a funky way and i would like to make that transformation on on the service and not every time and everywhere i have to save that object. Also, i use $save() because that is what i saw in https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: several ways you can do that, read up on $httpProvider interceptors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save method let you pass custom data to the request.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', function($resource){
   return $resource ('api/comments/');
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope, myFactory){
   $scope.myData = 'some data';

   myFactory.save($scope.myData, function(){
      //do something useful.
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {

$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
    //do something here
}

});
```

Comment: This would work, but does not feel very dry as i would have to use a non-reusable function every time and everywhere i need to save. Thus, what I would like is to move the required transformation of the data to the service. That is why I am asking for help on overriding the save function or perhaps shed some light on the other 2 non documented methods i mentioned in the question.

Comment: I dont know if i get it, but if you need to do the same action on every request you need to use trasnformRequest with $httpProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `$http.post` to resolve this problem so I can control any params.

Maybe that is not a good way, but it works.

Comment: I appreciate that but I am looking for clarity on how it is done via the $resource service

Comment: defeats the purpose of using `$resource`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('Post', function($resource, $q, $http){
  const r = $resource(`${baseUrl}api/post/:id`, {id: '@id'});

  // this will override the default save method
  r.save = (data) => {
   // do whatever with data
   const d = $q.defer();
   $http.put(`${baseUrl}api/post/`, data)
   .then(res => {
     d.resolve(res.data);
   })
   .catch(err => {
     d.reject(err)
   });

   // return the same promise format as $resource
   return {$promise: d.promise};
  };

  return r;
});
```